# Python error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pypresence'

Tags: python

Hi im new to python and i would know why does it say ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pypresence' when i try to run this code:

```
from pypresence import Presence
import time

client_id = '...'
RPC = Presence(client_id)
RPC.connect()

print(RPC.update(state="Lookie Lookie", details="A test of qwertyquerty's Python Discord RPC wrapper, pypresence!"))

while True:
    time.sleep(15)
```

*This code is copied from https://qwertyquerty.github.io/pypresence/html/info/examples.html*

also i already did pip install pypresence few times already

Comment: did you install pypresence?

Comment: If you're using Python3, use `pip3` instead of `pip`. If you're working in a virtual environment, you should activate your environment first, then run the `pip install pypresence` or `pip3 install pypresence`

Comment: yea i did do ```pip install pypresence``` few times already

Comment: Then make sure you're using the pip version that works with your Python version (pip for python 2 and pip3 for python 3)

Comment: if i use pip3 and run it just gives me a bunch of errors

Comment: if you use pip3, then you should run it using python3 `python3 your_script.py`

Comment: same thing, a bunch of errors

Comment: oh yea im also on python 3.8.5

Comment: When you used pip3, you did the right thing since you use python3 (3.8). The errors you got after that are because the `client_id` is not correct, so use a correct `client_id` and it should work.

Comment: @quasheletric what error are you getting while trying to install using pip3 ?

Comment: oh thanks i forgot about that

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the module first.

Do like this -> `pip install pypresence`

Edit for installing in python3 virtualenv:

Create a virtualenv like this:

`python3 -m venv env`

Activate the `env`

`source env/bin/activate`

Now, you are in python 3 env(make sure it is atleast python 3.5 a/c to module requirements).

Now, install the module and other modules which are required for running the script and you are good to go.

`pip install pypresence`

Comment: You are using `virtualenv`?

Comment: whats that im new to python

Comment: If you run `pip list | grep pypresence` in the terminal where you are running the script. What do you see?

Comment: this ```DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.
pypresence                             3.0.0```

Comment: That's the issue, you are running the script in python 2.7 which is not supported by this module.

Comment: Updated the answer, Can you try it now?

Comment: i found out why, it was bc i was not using pip3 to install and client id was wrong

Comment: when you are in python3 env, it automatically uses pip3.

Answer (score 0):

The module `pypresence` may not be available in the environment that you are running the code in.

You can install the required module with
`pip install pypresence`

Full details on the module can be found here - [pypresence 4.0.0](https://pypi.org/project/pypresence/)